# Python: Write Individual lists as columns in csv

Tags: python, csv

I am creating list for each data items, I have following data structure and at the end of iteration have have 6 lists that contains data points. Each list has same length, I want to generate each list as a column of csv file

Example:

```
columnOfList1, columnOfList2...
```

this is my code that generate multiple list of data: what I can't figureout is to generate csv file.

```
for (fn1, lst1), (fn2, lst2) in product(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    for vector1, vector2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
```

Comment: are you having trouble with the csv module, writing to a file, or organizing your data?

Comment: `NameError: name 'product' is not defined.` (I assume you're talking about `itertools.product`, but would you please put it in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you told, each list have the same length. Why do you don't do a "for" with this length?

Example:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    print lst[i], lst2[i], lst3[i], lst4[i], lst5[i]
```

Comment: why didn't i think of this :)

Answer (score 1):

Converting rows to lists is just *translation*. It's simply done with `zip`:

```
>>> foo
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> zip(*foo)
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4, 4, 4)]
```

So you can probably just do

```
>>> lsts = [l[1] for l in product(yourdicts)]
>>> csvwriter.writerows(zip(*lsts))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for this. First stack the arrays into columns:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> col1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> col2 = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> output = np.vstack((col1, col2)).T
>>> output
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Then write it out. You can just pass a filename, but here I've used StringIO to show the output:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO()
>>> np.savetxt(s, output, delimiter=',', fmt='%.7g')
>>> print s.getvalue()
1,4
2,5
3,6
```